# $.ajax({}); not working for type : POST in asp.net in jquery 1.10.2 min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

It works well for type= "GET" but in case of type = "POST" it returns NULL value.

```
 function __callbackprocessing(trdata) {
    var notfound = "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%' border='0' class='Top_Bar'><tbody><tr><td valign='center' align='left'><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' style='width: 100%'><tbody><tr><td class='Top_Bar_txt' valign='center' align='left' width='85'>Search Results :</td><td valign='center' align='right'><img height='16' alt='Basket' src='../images/Icon_add_basket.gif' width='20' /> </td><td valign='center' align='left'><table>";
    if (ExportToExcel) {
        $("#modalPopupMask").replaceWith("<div id='modalPopupMask' name='modalPopupMask'class='modalPopupMask'></div>");
        $('#imgProcess').replaceWith("<img src='../images/Processing_animation.gif' id='imgProcess' style='z-index: 2000; position: absolute; left: 450px; top: 300px;' align='center' valign='middle' />");
               }

    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",           
        //type: "POST",
         url: "../WebForms/Search.aspx",             
         data: "data=" + trdata,                          
         contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data, status) { });});
```

C# code : -
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String isPost = Request.Params["data"];
        isQuery = Request.QueryString["Search"];
}

Comment: where is the url in your code? please also put you c# code that returns your data.

Comment: Where does this "NULL value" appear?

Comment: I am update the my code with url and c# code, The page load event in that  String isPost = Request.Params["data"];,  ipost variable in that I got null values

Comment: Thanks for response ,  I am adding url,data  but not working, Plz suggest me

Answer (score -1):

If you are passing POST I recommend that you define the variables before pushing them through Ajax within your data.

Var submit = $('#submit').val();

Data: {submit:submit, etc:etc}

Also include the url that you are posting the data to.

Comment: I am add url and take value in variable ,and pass variable value  to Data, but still not working. Plz suggest me.

Comment: Have you defined the data id in your other script? Sorry for the late responses, I'm at work. Ajax needs to know the ID of the element you are passing the data through or it won't know what to grab.

Comment: Thanks for response , sry for late. I am include in that data id  and pass but still not working.

Comment: You need to pass every bit of data using the example above, or it won't work